# iPhone Apple Push Notification service

Tags: iphone

When i log in to iPhone developer programmer portal as admin, if go to App Id section 
i can see list of app id's.I want to enable for push notification.But in Action column there is nothing i am not getting configurable button. So i am not able to proceed further to get SSL certificate for my app.

Comment: This is a question about Apple's developer site, and not one about actual code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable the Push Notification Service, you must set the explicit name for your App ID, not the wildcard asterisk character. See the [iPhone Developer program user guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_developer_program_user_guide/iphone_developer_program_user_guide__standard_program_v2.5__final.pdf) for more information.